# Using information contained in text files

Tags: java

I have a problem with the task and I would like to ask for tips.

There are three text files with the names: doctors.txt, patients.txt, visits.txt.
They contain information about doctors, patients and home visits.
In each of the files, the data in the line are separated by tabs.

Using the information contained in the files, execute the following commands:

- find the doctor who has had the most visits.

I am having trouble reading these files. How do I do this to convert the data from these three text files?

I created the doctor, patient, visit, time classes and in the main I put the files into the blackboard.

```
enter code here
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File[] files = {new File("doctors.txt"), new File("patients.txt"),
                    new File("visits.txt")};
            for (File file : files) {
                if(file.isFile()) {
                    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                    String line;
                    try {
                        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: *the data in the line are separated by tabs*. I can understand it. But it will be helpful if you provide few sample data for better understanding.

Comment: You will need to wrap your file reader in a class/method, that will provide actions like, find doctor by id, group visits by doctor id.  It seems that You need to group by doctor content of visits file, then find given doctor in doctors file. But without any file content examples it is hard to give any working solution.

Comment: What is the first few lines of output?

Comment: Is it possible to put text files here??

Comment: You use add few sample lines. For example: `Dr. Prashant    9910`. Something like this so that everyone gets an idea of what they are working with.